# Python Requests not working on second get request when working with stream handler callback

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, python-requests, hacker-news-api

I am trying to play with the Hacker News API found [here](https://github.com/HackerNews/API), especially the live data section.

I am currently trying to print the response I get for every new item that I get from the `/v0/maxitem` API.

Given below is the code that I currently have:

```
import pyrebase
from config import config
import requests

firebase = pyrebase.initialize_app(config)
firebase_db = firebase.database()

_BASEURL_ = "https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/"

def print_response(id):
    headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
    print(_BASEURL_ + str(id) + ".json")
    response = requests.get(_BASEURL_ + str(id) + ".json", headers=headers)
    print(response.content)


def new_post_handler(message):
    print(message["data"])
    print_response(message["data"])

my_stream = firebase_db.child("/v0/maxitem").stream(new_post_handler,
                                                    stream_id="new_posts")
```

I am able to get a valid response the first time `requests.get` runs. But the second time, I always get a `NULL` value for the content of the response.

The `GET` URL works on postman though, able to get a valid response there. The issue seems to particularly be with how the `requests` module is treating the URL the second time.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Print the status code of the response to aid debugging:  `print(response.status_code)`

Comment: Interestingly, I get a 200 status code for the second request too.

Comment: Print the URL of both requests. Visit them in your browser. What do you see?

Comment: Both URLs work fine on the browser.

Comment: Maybe you're rate limited? Maybe there a race condition - the page may not be fully "live" yet.

Comment: Are you sure it's the response that shows null? You have a few `print` statements

Comment: I am sure the `response.content` shows b'null'.